# Entity Framework 6 and AsNonUnicode method

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using entity framework 6 and have exception "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String AsNonUnicode(System.String)' method". Here is what I do.

I have table Customers with email column defined as varchar(254) (non-Unicode).

In my mapping I have following line:

```
Property(t => t.Email).IsUnicode(false);
```

When I put my query like this:

```
var q = context.Customers.Where(t => t.Email == "a@gmail.com").Select(t => t.FirstName);
```

everything is fine, the constant is non-Unicode. However, if I use this code:

```
string email = "a@gmail.com";
var q = context.Customers.Where(t => t.Email == email);
```

the variable being generated is Unicode one, which results in not using index.

So, I tried using EntityFunctions.AsNonUnicode extension, which seemed to be designed for this:

```
string email = "a@gmail.com";
var q = context.Customers.Where(t => t.Email == EntityFunctions.AsNonUnicode(email));
```

However, I got an exception LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String AsNonUnicode(System.String)' method exception when trying to actually query data.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your EntityFunctions.AsNonUnicode is the one from EntityFramework.dll and not the one from System.Data.Entity dll? What namespace it is from (should be System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects)? If you have a reference to System.Data.Entity.dll in your project you should remove it.

Comment: That's what it, thank you. If you put it as an answer, I will mark it as the one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are not using EntityFnctions from System.Data.Entity.dll when using EF6. EF5 and EF6 are not binary compatible and ideally you should remove a reference to System.Data.Entity.dll if you are using EF6 to avoid confusing errors like this. In this particular case make sure you are using EntityFunctions from System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects namespace which is where EntityFunction type lives in EF6